# How to make Show and Hide Toggle Specific

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have created a simple "Show and Hide" toggle using Jquery but I want it to be specific to each div as I will be reusing the Class.

I know I have to use the (this) function but cant seem to place it correctly.

[Please see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2gv565t/)

many thanks for you kind help.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').toggle("toogle");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // attaching the click-event handler to the class:
    $('.showmenu').click(function () {
        // this is the DOM node of the clicked-element,
        // $(this) is the jQuery object formed from the clicked DOM node
        $(this)
          // traverses to the next sibling of the clicked element,
          // if it's a 'div' with the 'menu' class-name:
          .next('div.menu')
          // toggles that element:
          .toggle("toogle");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showmenu').click(function () {
        $(this).next('div.menu').toggle("toogle");
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Button1</li>
        <li>Button2</li>
        <li>Button3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Button1</li>
        <li>Button2</li>
        <li>Button3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Recommended Reading:

- [jQuery tree-traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Thanks David Great help !

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you explain why it expands out and not just straight down? see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smnnxn8j/

Comment: That's apparently what `toggle()` does; if you use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead, though, it seems closer to what you want: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/smnnxn8j/1/).

Comment: Thanks David! much appreciated, are you interested in any freelance opportunities?

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()`. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.menu').toggle("toogle");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.showmenu').click(function() {
         $(this).next().toggle("toggle");
    });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you explain why it expands out and not just straight down? see updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/smnnxn8j

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });
});
```

I'm assuming what you want is for each div to toggle the visibility of its contents when clicked.  The [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selector would get every list nested under the div, even if there are multiple ones.

I edited your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j2gv565t/1/).  Check it out, you also had an error in your html (an extra `</div>`).

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you explain why it expands out and not just straight down? see updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/smnnxn8j

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean.  It's expanding out to the right to accommodate the width of the div.  If you want it to expand out to the right less, use css to change the div width.